# MVC5 Url.Action not returning correct URL

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to use a Kendo Grid for a list of objects on my model, but the url's generated by the `.Create()` etc. methods are not generating the url correctly.

It doesn't appear to be just Kendo though because even in my controller using `Url.Action()` generates the wrong url.

```
// POST: Assessment/Create
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
[Route("eForms/Assessment/Create")] // <-- Tried with and without this
public ActionResult Create(AssessmentPoco model)
{
    var x = Url.Action(("Allergy_Read", "Assessment");
}

    //POST: Assessment/Allergy_Read
    [HttpPost, ActionName("Allergy_Read")]
    [Route("AllergyRead", Name = "Allergy_Read")]
    public ActionResult Allergy_Read([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, AssessmentAllergiesSection model) //, int id)
    {
        return Json(new[] { model }.ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState));
    }
```

Expected: `eForms/Assessment/Allergy_Read`

Actual: `/?action=Allergy_Read&controller=Assessment`

Route config:

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("");
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        //web forms default
        routes.MapPageRoute(
            routeName: "WebFormDefault", 
            routeUrl: "", 
            physicalFile:"~/default.aspx");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name:  "API",
            url: "eforms/api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new {controller="Customer", action="GetCustomers", id = UrlParameter.Optional}
            );

        ////mvc default
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "eforms/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "IncidentReports", action = "Search", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

Not sure what else could be at fault here (besides my brain), any ideas?

Clarifications (from comments):

- We are using Areas
- Global.asax is calling RegisterRoutes (also tried turning it off no change)

Update:
This project is a newly added MVC project to an existing ASP.Net WebForms app. I updated the Route config because I was using looking at the wrong one.

Comment: Are you using areas?

Comment: In your global.asax, did you make sure that your RegisterRoutes is called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using routeAttribute, so put a name inside it and use Html.RouteLink or Url.RouteUrl instead of Url.Action().

Example:

```
[Route("menu", Name = "mainmenu")]
public ActionResult MainMenu() { ... }
```

Usage in View:

```
<a href="@Url.RouteUrl("mainmenu")">Main menu</a>
```

Comment: I get this error:
A route named 'Allergy_Read' could not be found in the route collection. Parameter name: name

Comment: Put [RoutePrefix("Assessment")] just before the class declaration and try to see if you get any good results.

Comment: [RoutePrefix("Assessment")]
    public class AssessmentController : BaseFormController
Same Error

Comment: This is not the answer I was hoping for, but it was the only way we could solve our problem. But to get this to work we needed to add "routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();" to the RegisterRoutes().
Not what we wanted but for now it's the only solution we have.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this code in controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
   {
      [Route("AllergyRead", Name = "Allergy_Read")]   
      public ActionResult Allergy_Read()
      {
      return View();
      }
   }
```

And:
   @Html.RouteLink("Allergy Read", "Allergy_Read")

Give me the right route to action. I can't figure out why your implementation isn't working.